# сбор данных с другого сайта

Tags: php, jquery, curl

Есть вот такой код на php и js:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<?php

echo file_get_contents('https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-saratov-5032/');

?>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var wth = $(".tab-weather__value_l").text();
    var str = wth.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var ifminus = str.search( /^(?!-)\D*/ );
    if (ifminus === 0) {

            var plusint = str.replace( /^(?!-)\D*/, "");
            var plusint = plusint.replace( /\,/, ".");
            var plusint = plusint - plusint - plusint;
        console.log(plusint);
    }


    console.log(wth);
    console.log(str);
    console.log(ifminus);
    console.log("WATCH HERE");
    console.log(parseFloat(plusint, 10));
    console.log("WATCH HERE_2");



    if (plusint > 0) {
        console.log("WORKING");
    } else { console.log("UPS");}
});

</script>


<p>Checking</p>
```

Он выводит всю страницу другого сайта у себя, и там ищет, что нужно, и успешно находит... Вот только отображение всей этой страницы мне не нужно, а ничего умнее чем создать див под него и скрыть - я не придумал. Подскажите, может есть более цивилизованный метод?

Comment: Вы же обозначили curl как одну из меток тематики вопроса. Почему не используете?

Comment: я его понять толком не могу, думал может тут подскажут

Comment: зачем вам curl если вы уже получили страницу через `file_get_contents` ? возьмите [tag:simple-html-dom] или аналоги, и вытащите данные. но лучше получайте эти данные через крон и сохраняйте куда-нибудь.

Comment: и посмотрите вообще на  информеры https://www.gismeteo.ru/informers/, мб с их помощью проще решить проблему будет

Answer (score 1):

Удалось сократить выводимую часть в 1 див, так что по сути, все работает =)

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-saratov-5032/');
    $first_step = explode( 'tab-weather__value_l">' , $html );
    $second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
    echo '<div style="display:none" id="cc">'.$second_step[0].'</div>';
?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var wth = $("#cc").text();
    var str = wth.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var ifminus = str.search( /^−/ );

    if (ifminus === 0) {

        var plusint = str.replace( /^−/, "");
        var plusint = plusint.replace( /\,/, ".");
        var plusint = plusint - plusint - plusint;

    } else {

        var plusint = str;
        var plusint = plusint.replace( /\,/, ".");

    }

    var rw = parseFloat(plusint, 10);
    if (rw < -15) {

        $("#weather").html("<div style='color:red'>Монтаж запрещен</div>");

    } else { 

        $("#weather").html("<div style='color:green'>Монтаж разрешен</div>");

    }

});

</script>


<div id="weather">Problem Detected</div>
```